# Many button->container elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a few equal buttons and containers;

Something like:

```
<div>
   <button class="myCoolButton">
       btn1
   </button>
</div>

<div class="myCoolContainer">
   container
</div>

<div>
   <button class="myCoolButton">
       btn1
   </button>
</div>

<div class="myCoolContainer">
   container
</div>

<div>
   <button class="myCoolButton">
       btn1
   </button>
</div>

<div class="myCoolContainer">
   container
</div>
```

So when user clicks on button i need to show some info in to container below. But how i can understand what container i need to use? Is it good to put attribute with bindend container to button? What is best practice?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Neir0/wJnaG/2/)

NOTE: calendar must be showed in yellow rectangle

Comment: The container you want to show the info in is the parent of the button?

Comment: @Matijs No, it is not. It located below button container. Actually it could be everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('buttonselector').click(function(){ 
      $(this) // get clicked button
      .parent() // parent of clicked buton, i.e div at odd place
       .next() // next div to parent div of clicked button, i.e, div at even place
        .html('set some value') // set value to adjacent div
})
```

**EDIT**

```
<div>
   <button id="btn1">
       btn1
   </button>
</div>

<div id="Container_btn1">
   container
</div>

$('#btn1').click(function(){ 
        var name= $(this).attr('id'); 
        $("#container_"+ name).html('set some value')
});
```

Comment: It is good straightforward solution. But what if i a little change html code? For example move container uder on in to a footer of a page?

Comment: if target div is located anywhere on page, then you need to identify it. Either pass target div to your function or use prefix "container" + ButtonID to pair button and div

Comment: You somehow have to ensure a little structure in your document. If they are completely arbitrary spread across the page and they all have the same name, how could anyone tell, which DIV to show? When the HTML structure changes, you'd adjust the Javascript part accordingly. But they have to either have a unique name that matches the button or be a child or next element in the DOM tree.

Comment: @Sebastian Wramba Yeah, but i asked in my question what is best practive to identity my container? Is it good <button id="btn1" /> <div id="container1"></div> and when user click on button i get button id and replace "btn" on "container" string to get container id. Or i must to do someting else?

Comment: hungryMind updated his answer. I think this would be the best thing to do. Identify the corresponding container by it's name, not the position in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(".myCoolButton").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("div").next().html("triggered");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myCoolButtons = $('.myCoolButton');
var myCoolContainers = $('.myCoolContainer');
myCoolButtons.click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index(myCoolButtons);
    myCoolContainers.eq(index).html('CoolButton right before me is clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myCoolButton').click(function(){

      $(this).parent().next('div').html('hello world');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NNpvZ/

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try this, http://jsfiddle.net/konglie/zpVWY/

```
    $('button.myCoolButton').click(function(){
    var container = $(this).parent().next('div.myCoolContainer')[0];
    $(container).html('clicking on ' + $(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place buttons all over the page and corresponding containers all over the page, then it would be very hard to find the right container without extending your structure. Did you consider adding a new class that matches container with the button? in that case no matter where you would have it, you would be sure which container you want to refer to. For example you could add class button1 for button and container1 for container (instead of ID's there might be any common pattern).